# Magento 2 php code not displaying all top nav links

Tags: php, magento2

I have added some non category nav links to the top nav using newly created module. The code displays Test page1 and test page3 but not test page2. How do I get the code to display all links?

```
<?php
namespace testMod\navUpdate\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Topmenu implements ObserverInterface
{

/**
 * @param EventObserver $observer
 * @return $this
 */
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{
   /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menu */
   $menu = $observer->getMenu();
   $tree = $menu->getTree();
   $data = [
       'name'      => __('Test page'),
       'id'        => 'test-page',
       'url'       => 'test-page',
   ];
   $node = new Node($data, 'id', $tree, $menu);
   $menu->addChild($node);
   $data = [
       'name'      => __('Test page2'),
       'id'        => 'test-page2',
       'url'       => 'test-page2',
   ];
   $node = new Node($data, 'id2', $tree, $menu);
   $menu->addChild($node);
   $data = [
        'name'      => __('Test page3'),
        'id'        => 'test-page3',
        'url'       => 'test-page3',
   ];
   $node = new Node($data, 'id3', $tree, $menu);
   $menu->addChild($node);
   return $this;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Honestly, your code looks correct. I think the issue  might be somewhere else.

Comment: I worked it out, all the 'id' s need to be the same